# Understanding the "Wigner's Friend" thought experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers

I'm having trouble understanding what the paradox is in the [Wigner's friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend) thought experiment. I've read a number (but not all) of the other questions about Wigner's friend here on this site although none of the ones I read seem to address the source of my confusion:

It seems to me that there is no paradox, because the act of the friend performing the measurement in the lab -- even before the friend became consciously aware of the result -- surely had some effect outside the lab, since the lab is clearly not a closed system (otherwise Wigner wouldn't have been able to communicate with his friend).

The effect might have been minute but it would have been there. I can construct infinite situations where information reached the outside of the lab prior to Wigner asking his friend for the results, but I cannot construct any situations where this wouldn't be the case.

For example, perhaps the friend observed the results on the display of an electronic device. In this case the power consumption of the lab may have differed by a few electrons or so depending on the information that was displayed. Or perhaps the friend heard the results from an audible speaker of some sort. In that case at least some number of particles would have had different vibration states in a chain reaction that ultimately made its way out of the lab in some form or another. Or perhaps it was a chemistry experiment where the result was a certain color. In that case light reflecting off the result would've interacted with something or other surely causing some sort of miniscule chain reaction that led to a subtle change in a few particles outside of the lab.

So the question doesn't seem to be about *when* the wave function collapsed, but rather the question is whether Wigner -- outside the lab -- has the technology and knowledge to measure whatever information made its way out of the lab prior to just asking his friend what the result was. If Wigner would have had some infinitely precise measure of, say, electric current flowing into the lab, and precise knowledge about what to expect, then he would have observed the result of the experiment before his friend even became aware of it.

It seems, then, like there's no paradox. There's simply Wigner's inability to detect information about the experiment's result without just asking his friend what it was.

What am I missing? Why is there debate about this?

Comment: Wigner's friend, just like Schroedinger's cat, is a good way to confuse yourself about quantum mechanics. Quantum mechanics is simply about reversible and irreversible energy transfer. As long as the transfers are reversible, we can't know anything about the system. "knowledge" requires that something irreversible happens that leaves an "eternal" change in the environment. All of these "paradoxes" disappear immediately as soon as you learn to find the actual physical irreversibility. I would also advise everybody NOT to use the word "information" in this context. Physics is about energy.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are missing the whole point of the argument by nitpicking on a technicality.

The fact of the matter is that we currently have sufficiently good control on the (quantum) noise in macroscopically large systems that we can actually observe the Wigner's friend experiment in reality.

That is, your insistence upon having the important and relevant information leak out of the lab is an irrelevant technicality. The fact of the matter is that we are increasingly able to actually perform the experiment without such a leak, and we observe the interference patterns characteristic of quantum behaviour. So you should be paying attention to it being reality.

Comment: Can you support your claims by a reference to such experiments?

Comment: There are a bit too many to reference. These days we can put, say, entire mirrors into quantum superposition. Going back half a century we would have trouble with mere small molecules. The field of cold atoms and cavity QED and photonics have progressed too much to really cite one by one. What we can say, is that there is no known upper bound in the size of a system that we can experimentally put into a quantum superposition, and thus we have to seriously take into consideration that such an upper bound does not exist.

Comment: You're missing the point. Name one, not all of them. "we can actually observe the Wigner's friend experiment in reality"...?

Comment: Unless you are one of the few who really believe that the human consciousness breaks quantum theory in some form, the ability for macroscopically large systems to be put into quantum superposition not just implies that detectors, but also humans, can be put into quantum superposition. It is just a matter of scale, and as mentioned prior, there is no known upper bound of a system size that cannot be quantum superposed. You are the one missing the point I am making, and the whole point of the Wigner's friend thought experiment.

Comment: Take it easy, man. I agree with much of what you are saying. But you are making it sound like there is an actual experiment for Wigner's friend which you could refer to, which you don't, which seems like a glaring omission in your answer...

Comment: I am not that easy to get angry; that was not yet angry talk. I was just pointing out that some stuff that is hidden in my first answer, that really is not as glaring of an omission as you think it is. I was also in a hurry because as I was typing my answer, the other guy's post appeared.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent There's no rush; I am reading all the answers and waiting for more, as well. :) I am trying to understand why the information leak is a technicality but having a bit of trouble (I don't disbelieve you, I just am having trouble understanding).

Comment: The Wigner in the thought experiment doesn't require consciousness, right? Also, does the answer that Wigner's friend gives Wigner represent *general* information leak outside of the lab system (and is that why the "information leak" that *I* mentioned is just a technicality)?

Comment: There are some rare folks who really believe in consciousness collapse. If they believe cats and bacteria can also do it, then at least there is something to respect about them. Feels like the whole ``I don't know quantum, I don't know consciousness, so they must be linked". If you do not believe consciousness is inherently special, then Wigner and friend do not need to be conscious. We tend to not speak of "information leak" but rather "getting entangled". The outside of the lab starts getting relevantly entangled with pointer states. Irrelevant degrees of freedom doesnt matter!

Comment: Wigner's friend is not about noise. It's about the question of the difference between isolated (reversible) and non-isolated (irreversible) quantum systems.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine Wigner's friend builds his lab a light year from Earth out in deep space, far beyond the orbit of Pluto. Wigner is sat at home on Earth, and it takes any signal at least a year to travel from the lab to Earth.

Wigner's friend makes a measurement, but Wigner will not find out about it for another year. Wigner has made no observation of the lab experiment, and is totally isolated from it by the lightspeed limit. From Wigner's point of view, modelling the lab as a giant quantum system, has the wavefunction collapsed?

Now suppose Wigner starts moving at high speed, remaining close to Earth. In special relativity, simultaneity is relative. Wigner can find a reference frame in which the lab experiment is still in the past. So has the wavefunction collapsed *now?* Can the collapse have occurred, from Wigner's now-moving point of view, up to a year *before* the experiment has taken place? Or does the wavefunction somehow *uncollapse*, since it is no longer in Wigner's future but in Wigner's past?

Wigner's Friend is a *thought-experiment* intended to provoke questions about what happens in observation-mediated-collapse interpretations when an observer is modelled as a quantum system that is itself subject to observation. Wigner's friend observes the particle and *objectively* collapses the wavefunction. For Wigner's quantum model of the lab to be correct, he has to be able to model that nonlinear 'collapse' change of state *without* himself making an observation of the lab system - i.e. the linear time evolution of isolated quantum states according to the Schrödinger equation cannot apply when the physical entity involved contains a conscious being. There is something special about *observers* as physical systems that allows them to trigger non-deterministic, nonlinear, irreversible collapse, that non-observer systems don't share. Human minds can deviate from the laws of physics that apply to inanimate, unaware objects. (Wigner himself didn't find this argument entirely convincing, and it has to be said there are holes in it.)

It is not required that a thought-experiment be easy or practical to carry out, or possible with today's technology. It only requires that it be conceivable *in principle*. However, in this case it so happens that the lightspeed limit on observation gives us an easy way to implement complete isolation from any physical effects, unless one is willing to surrender causality.

Comment: You are confusing yourself (unnecessarily) about the difference between classical and quantum uncertainty.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unclear in what way? Your comment is unclear.

Comment: If it is just about collapse of the wavefunction then there is no point in talking about Wigner, because the Friend alone can collapse the wavefunction, just awaiting transfer of the information to Wigner. Yes, it is mildly interesting that Wigner would not have yet been able to know that the wavefunction has collapsed. But it is much more potent that the Friend could be put into a quantum superposition, and that is where Wigner's Friend experiment is particularly interesting to consider.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Yes. The idea that an observer can be in superposition leads naturally on to the Everett interpretation, it was one of Everett's main supporting arguments in his thesis. But I was trying to concentrate on the Q - how can you construct an isolated lab that won't leak info to Wigner, and why is the concept considered paradoxical. In the Everett interpretation it's not paradoxical, and anyway Wigner was not thinking about that when he came up with the idea. And tempting as it is, I try not to pepper *every* answer with my MWI-advocacy! Should I, here?

Comment: No, because MWI is not the only interpretation that would have the friend be in a superposition. And no, the Q was not about describing the basic Wigner's friend experiment, that you did.

Comment: "And no, the Q was not about describing the basic Wigner's friend experiment" I don't follow. I didn't say it was. The Q explains his problem with understanding the scenario "I can construct infinite situations where information reached the outside of the lab prior to Wigner asking his friend for the results, but I cannot construct any situations where this wouldn't be the case." I constructed such a situation to answer the direct Q: "What am I missing?"

Answer (score -1):

I fully agree with you. There is no paradox because one premise of this experiment, that one can perfectly isolate the lab, is not possible to achieve.

Any macroscopic change inside the lab (like a pointer moving from left to right) would be accompanied by a change in the electric, magnetic and gravitational fields outside. They can be in principle measured there, so, the collapse takes place when the measurement inside the lab is performed, not when the lab is open.

Comment: A nucleus that has a 4.5 billion year half life is a pretty well isolated system, wouldn't you think? If that's not good enough, I present you with proton decay.

Comment: A nucleus has a positive charge and therefore it's in interaction with all other charged particles in the universe. It also has mass so it interacts gravitationally with all masses in the universe. Being stable and being isolated are different things.

Comment: For the purposes of a radioactive decay a long lived nucleus is an extremely well isolated system. That we can still bounce it around at low energy (electrostatic interaction and chemistry) and nothing happens is a fortunate coincidence, otherwise there would be no stable matter in the universe at all. It would all disintegrate into photons almost immediately.

Comment: @FlatterMann, what's your point here? What is the relevance of radioactive decay to Wigner's friend scenario? This experiment is about macroscopic superpositions. A nucleus is not a macroscopic system. It's not true that stability requires isolation. You only need some sort of equilibrium. A rock absorbs/emits photons all the time yet it's stable enough.

Comment: The point here is to realize that all systems in nature are open and they all decay, eventually, to a trivial ground state. This means that all our "reversible" theories (like the Schroedinger equation or Newton's laws) are merely approximations of reality, which includes intellectual nonsense like Wigner's friend (and Schroedinger's cat), which are designed to confuse the beginner with an insufficient separation between facts and theory.

Comment: @FlatterMann Hello. Do you also believe that we need different equations than these reversible ones to explain the irreversibility of measurements on paper? You've told me before that QFT already explains this well, but the evolution law in QFTs is also a Schrodinger equation of the form $i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=H\psi$. So I am thinking we may need new theories that are irreversible. I'm interested in your view.

Comment: @RyderRude Of course we need a different equations for irreversible processes than for reversible ones. We needed them in classical mechanics, already. We used to teach the difference between elastic and inelastic collision even at the high school level even when I was still a teenager.  QFT simply doesn't suffer from the ontological problems of non-relativistic QM because it treats quantum systems correctly: with scattering theory rather than an unphysical wave function approach.